# Paginación refrescando la página o AJAX

Tags: angularjs, ajax, web

Estoy con un proyecto en el que arrojo los resultados de una búsqueda en pantalla. Como pueden ser muchos resultados los obtenidos estoy implementando la paginación (usando el paginator de Django, pero no viene al caso). Mi consulta es la siguiente:

¿Es mejor implementar una función `AJAX` que se encargue de la paginación (en este caso usaría AngularJS (Angular 1) y un ng-repeat para manejar los datos devueltos por el servidor)? o por cuestión de sencillez ¿es mejor usar el servidor y `refrescar la página`? ¿Por que?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a experiencia de usuario seria mejor ir cargando el resto de elementos con AJAX, es mas rápido ya que hay menos latencia en devolver JSON que HTML además de que no se recarga la página.
En cuanto a SEO, lo más conveniente es renderizar el html desde el servidor para que los motores de búsqueda indexen la pagina correctamente.

En cualquier caso, depende de la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte la molestia en responder. Al final me decidí por el AJAX y el client side rendering. Saludos!